# SQL Server various stored procedure temp table results to JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, stored-procedures

Bit of a complicated one this as it requires knowing very little from the start except that each stored procedure returns a single dataset (which is a temp table).

I can't use OPENQUERY or OPENROWSET

I'm using SQL server 2012

What I would like to do is have a single point of entry which builds a me a string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuildMeAString (@spname varchar(30))
AS

  -- select results from a stored procedure

  SELECT * INTO #temp FROM @spname

  -- get the column names to build the first record of the JSON string

  -- loop through the rows and build a JSON string for each row

GO
```

I'd like it this sort of way so I can change any stored procedure being called without needing to have it formatted in a standard way

Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this need to be done in SQL Server? It would be significantly easier to have a generic class in your application layer that serializes the table returned from the stored procedure. You probably could write some long winded method to do it, but it will be horribly inefficient, and pretty much the epitome of ramming a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: I agree that it would be easier to do it via a class in the application layer, but each time I have to add a new type of JSON format for a specific job, I have to recode, test and deploy a new version of the application layer, which is what I am trying to get round.
If I can get the DB to just return me the JSON, I can do any changes to stored procedure results without having to do any changes.
I might just have to be a bit cleverer as to what I can do in the application layer to make it more generic.

Comment: If you can't use OPENQUERY, or OPENROWSET, and can't do it in the appropriate layer then I think you are running out of options. Do you really expect to be making so many changes to your stored procedures, and so frequently that updating the Data Access Layer at the same time as the SP is going to become so arduous that it warrants spending hours, or days trying to implement a generic solution that ultimately sacrifices performance to avoid a few key strokes up the road?

Comment: Probably Gareth, I'll have a rethink about the design

Comment: @GarethD and Mike: there is a way to accomplish this without using `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET`. I am typing that up now. But I will say, in regards to the first sentence of this question: a stored procedure result set is not a temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ways to accomplish something this dynamic, especially when dealing with result sets from Stored Procedures, is to use one of the following:

- `OPENQUERY`
- `OPENROWSET`
- SQLCLR
- A combination of the [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) DMV and the [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) built-in function (both introduced in SQL Server 2012)

You said that you can't use the first two so that leaves SQLCLR, and `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` + `CONCAT` (technically `CONCAT` isn't required, but it will make this a bit easier).

---

SQLCLR has probably best for this type of operation since it will allow you to:

- skip the temp table entirely, and
- get the column names at the same time as the data (column datatypes aren't needed since there is no temp table in this approach)

Using this method you would:

- Create a `SqlCommand` of the stored procedure to execute (or any query, really)
- Call the `ExecuteReader()` method of the `SqlCommand`
- Call either the `GetName()` or `GetSchemaTable()` method of the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) to get the column names
- Call the `Read()` method of the `SqlDataReader` in a `while` loop to get each row
- Construct the JSON in the loop, calling `GetValue(ordinal).ToString()` for each field
- Build the JSON document into a `StringBuilder`

---

If not using SQLCLR, then you will need to store the result set of the Stored Procedure into a temp table so that you can then transform / format it while SELECTing the data out of the temp table.

Using this method you would:

- Call `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to get the field names and datatypes
- Build a Dynamic SQL string that both creates a table variable and the `SELECT` statement (also in that inner Dynamic SQL context) that gets the data out of the table variable and formats it as JSON.
- Call the Dynamic SQL via `sp_executesql` so that you can pass the resulting JSON string back to the outer / current SQL context.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetJSONfromResultSet
(
  @Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,
  @TestMode BIT = 0
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A);
DECLARE @TempData TABLE (',
        @Concat NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SET @Output = N''''; -- declared by sp_executesql call
SELECT @Output += CONCAT(@CRLF, N''{'', @CRLF,';

SELECT @SQL += @CRLF + N'[' + cols.name + N'] ' +
               ISNULL(cols.user_type_name, cols.system_type_name) +
               IIF(cols.is_nullable = 0, N' NOT', N'') + N' NULL,',
       @Concat += @CRLF + N'N''   "' + cols.name + N'": ' +
       N'"'', ' + cols.name + N', N''"' + -- make this a CASE to handle string vs number
       N','', @CRLF,'
FROM   sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@Query, NULL, NULL) cols
ORDER BY cols.column_ordinal;

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1);
SET @SQL += @CRLF + N');' + @CRLF + @CRLF;
SET @SQL += N'INSERT INTO @TempData' + @CRLF;
SET @SQL += N'  ' + @Query + N';' + @CRLF + @CRLF;

SET @Concat = STUFF(@Concat, LEN(@Concat) - 9, 1, N'');
SET @Concat += @CRLF + N'N''},'')' + @CRLF;
SET @Concat += N'FROM @TempData;' + @CRLF;
SET @Concat += N'SET @Output = LEFT(@Output, LEN(@Output) - 1);' + @CRLF + @CRLF;

--SET @Concat += N'PRINT @Output;' + @CRLF; -- optional inner debug

SET @SQL += @Concat;

IF (@TestMode = 1)
BEGIN
  PRINT @SQL;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_executesql
    @SQL,
    N'@Output NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
    @Output = @JSON OUTPUT;
END;
GO
```

Test with:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP(5) * FROM sys.objects';
EXEC dbo.GetJSONfromResultSet @SQL, N'', 1
GO

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP(5) * FROM sys.objects',
        @JSONout NVARCHAR(MAX);
EXEC dbo.GetJSONfromResultSet @SQL, @JSON = @JSONout OUTPUT;

SELECT @JSONout;

PRINT @JSONout;
```

So this does work in pure T-SQL, but not if you are using SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2. And `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` has a whole list of restrictions, such as not working on stored procedures that user temp tables or Dynamic SQL, etc. SQLCLR works on all versions starting at SQL Server 2005, and doesn't have those other restrictions.

Comment: @thepirat000 Well, for this type of stuff it certainly wasn't intended, so kinda year. But I also did say that SQLCLR was the better choice here. I was just showing that it _could_ be done in pure T-SQL, mainly because of the overwhelming belief that something like this cannot be done ;-).

Comment: Great answer but I think I'll move some stuff back a step to the application layer and make it more generic with some data dictionary stuff instead to still make it more DB driven.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuildMeAString (@spname varchar(30))
AS

  -- select results from a stored procedure

  exec('SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ' + @spname + '


  SELECT * FROM #temp -- <-- do here what ever process you want.
  ')
```

If you use dynamic query it should be fairly easy.

LE :

Here is the query that selectes the columns from the temp table.

```
ALTEr PROCEDURE BuildMeAString (@spname varchar(30))
AS

  -- select results from a stored procedure  SELECT * FROM #temp -- <-- do here what ever process you want.

  exec('SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ' + @spname + '



  SELECT 
    c.name,
    t.Name,
    c.max_length,
    c.precision    
    FROM    
     tempdb.sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN 
      tempdb.sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tempdb.sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tempdb.sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#temp'')
  ')
```

Comment: Can you get the definitions of the columns and their datatypes for a temp table in dynamic SQL?

Comment: Regardless, can you do ??
    exec('SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ' + @spname + ')

Comment: @mikelittlewood what do you mean? I ran the procedure with a table as parameter and it runs OK.

Comment: Ah my bad .... @spname = stored procedure returning a temp table dataset. I did mention that at the beginning.

Comment: @mikelittlewood No, it is not possible to `SELECT INTO FROM EXEC` in pure T-SQL without using the two things that you said you couldn't use: `OPENQUERY` and `OPENROWSET`.